# SQL Server 2014 restore backup failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to restore a backup file to SQL Server 2014 but I keep getting the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup of the system database on the device C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\model_LogBackup_2014-12-16_15-48-23.bak cannot be restored because it was created by a different version of the server (12.00.2254) than this server (12.00.4213). (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

I created the backup using the same installation of SQL server 2014 using the same machine, I have no clue how the version changed from 12.00.2254 to 12.0.4213.0 and I also can't tell which is the newer version. I'm stuck I need to restore the backup file and all the posts online didn't suggest a definite answer to this problem.

Is there a way of changing the version of the current server to match the backup file (or the other way around). I thought about reinstalling but not sure how to end up having the exact version?

Thanks

Comment: Which system database are you trying to restore?  For system databases, you typically will have to restore to an instance with an identical version number as the instance from which the backup was created.

Comment: @DMason I'm trying to restore the model database. How can I insure they are identical?

Comment: Take a look at a [SQL Server Version List](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/).  From what I see, the source instance (v 12.00.2254) would need to have SP1 installed, followed by the [MS15-058 patch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/MS15-058), which was recently released by MS.  I believe that would "synch" up both instances to the same version.  Presumably, you could then take a backup of `model` from the upgraded instance and restore it to the other instance.

Comment: @DMason Thanks. I installed the SP1 but couldn't complete the MS15-058 patch update, it complained about the version again. Still can't restore the database.

Comment: 1. Why weren't you able to install MS15-058?  
2. You did take a new backup of `model` *after* installing SP1, right?

Comment: @DMason I got the following error trying to install it:
The version of SQL Server instance MSSQLSERVER does not match the version expected by the SQL Server update. The installed SQL Server product version is 12.1.4100.1, and the expected SQL Server version is 12.0.2000.8.

Comment: why do I need to create a new backup of the model database? It's empty and i'm trying to restore the old backup that I have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84834/discussion-between-dmason-and-phdeveloper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL-Server 2014 **SP1**, there are **breaking changes** to the restoreheader definition (3 **new** fields), if you use it, you should have a look at this thread:

[RESTORE HEADERONLY Error 3013 after the sp1 was applied to SQL Server 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631135/restore-headeronly-error-3013-after-the-sp1-was-applied-to-sql-2014/33258983#33258983)